# UIRefreshControl not working in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

**Note:** I find many solution but not working, i want that proper answer so please do not mark as duplicated.

**my code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    IArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self doSomethingWithTheJson];
    refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTable:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.CriTable addSubview:refreshControl];
    [self.CriTable sendSubviewToBack:refreshControl];
}

- (void)refreshTable:(id)sender {
    //TODO: refresh your data
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    [self.CriTable reloadData];
}
```

I have 2 question :

(1) UIRefreshControl can work without UITabBarCotroller?

(2) if it works than what was the issue in my code?

Comment: Can you show how it doesn't work? What happens with your `UIRefreshControl`?

Comment: @trungduc thank for response.app run on simulator there pull to refresh not working.

Comment: `UIRefreshControl` is displayed normally but your `tableView` isn't reloaded. Is it right?

Comment: @trungduc: yup. can you see my code if problem in code than suggest please.

Comment: Actually I don't see any problem in your code. Can you put a break point and make sure `refreshTable:` method is called? And do you call `reloadData` on main queue?

Comment: app not crash but pull not working in  tableview. got it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169322/discussion-between-rb1509-and-trungduc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got my solution. in my case i set `tableview` bounces marks as unselected.
just set `tableview` bounces as selected.